# accessing class methods in navigationOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a method in class which I need to access when I press a button in navigation options.

I have followed this approach after GitHub react native issue.
[Github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/145)

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: i18n.t('viewben'),
    header: ({ state }) => ({
        right: <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate('home');
            }}>
                <Image style={{ marginRight: 20 }} source={require('../../../resources/toolbar/home_white.png')} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight >
                <Image style={{ marginRight: 10 }} source={require('../../../resources/toolbar/edit_white.png')} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={state.params.handleDelete()}>
                <Image style={{ marginRight: 10 }} source={require('../../../resources/toolbar/delete_white.png')} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>,

    }),
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.themeColor,
        //  top: 30
    }
});



_deleteBen() {

    Alert.alert(i18N.t('delBen'), i18N.t('sureben'), [
        {
            text: i18N.t('confirm'), onPress: () => {



            }
        },
        { text: i18N.t('canc'), onPress: () => { }, style: 'cancel' },

    ], { cancelable: false });
};



componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        handleDelete: this._deleteBen
    });
}
```

**render code**

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainWrapper} >
            <ScrollView>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>{i18n.t('bendetails')} </Text>
                {/* <Text style={styles.headerAccNo}>{this.state.stViewAccountNo}</Text> */}
                <FlatList style={styles.flatList} data={this.state.stAccntDetail} renderItem={this._renderList} />

                <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>
            <TouchableOpacity  >
                <Image style={{ marginTop: 10, height: 50, alignSelf: 'center', marginRight: 10 }} source={require('../../../resources/toolbar/edit_white.png')} />
                <Text >edit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._deleteBen()} >
                <Text >delete</Text>
                <Image style={{ marginTop: 10, height: 50, alignSelf: 'center', marginRight: 10 }} source={require('../../../resources/toolbar/delete_white.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

I'm getting error like cant access 'Params' of undefined. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. I have included render code too.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your invoking `handleDelete` at run time in `navigationOptions`

make and arrow function instead, like so:

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={() => state.params.handleDelete()}
>
```

Also you should bind `_deleteBen` method with `this` context.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        handleDelete: this._deleteBen.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Comment: Its throwing error like "Objects are not valid as a react child.

Comment: you're rendering an `object` somewhere in your code, maybe in `_renderList`

Comment: the `error` shows up when an `event` happens or when the `component` renders?